# New installation of EE: Can I import entries from another installation and keep the entry_ids the same?

Tags: import, export

So I have an old, bloated installation of EE with way too many addons etc, etc. I'd like to get a clean installation up and running and import all the old entries into the new setup, keeping the entry_ids the same (for at least one channel anyway).

What steps would I need to take to import the old channel data and keep the entry_ids the same?

Comment: I don't think this is possible - I have put the original entry_id into a custom field for reference sake on imports.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's possible but it would require some major MYSQL.

But what I'm thinking is you set up the new site, set up the fields, channels, etc you want then get to moving the data from one table to its new version.

I've done something similar with moving field data between new channels and fields, but I don't use MYSQL often so I can't help much further, unfortunatly.

You may have to create some dummy entries to get your entry IDs up, (I can't remember how EE handled that part).

Obviously a massive task, made even bigger if you have a lot of entries.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/zeal-smart-export to export data from old site and datagrab module to import the data in new site.
Unfortunately, Entry id will change for sure